# About using arguments passed to the CheckedChanged event of Checkbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I display the value of the "Text" property of a checkbox when it is clicked?

So with the CheckedChanged event, two arguments of type sender & eventArgs are passed.

How do I the same using these arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but do you possibly also want to unset it if it's unchecked?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CType(sender, CheckBox).Checked Then
        Label1.Text = CType(sender, CheckBox).Text
    Else
        Label1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged with both C# and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), which are you using? Depending on this, you can use one of the following to get the CheckBox which fired the argument.

C#:

```
(CheckBox)sender
```

VB:

```
CType(sender, CheckBox)
```

You can then check the Text property of the object.

Comment: so I need to do the following in vb.net??

lblText.text=CType(sender.CheckBox).text

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answers suggested thus far are overkill in that the sub has the "Handles" qualifier... This means the ONLY time this will get called is when the Checkbox1 is modified. So you could use: `Checkbox1.text` directly.

The answers above are better suited for a more generic case where you want the SAME routine to HANDLE many checkboxes and so need to down_select to the appropriate ("calling") checkbox.

The subtlety here, Mr. Tejas, is that the NAME of the SUB (i.e. Checkbox1_CheckChanged) may or may not have anything to do with Checkbox1 depending upon the HANDLES phrase at the end.

Comment: no but i want it to handle for more that 1 checkboxes. So the code suggested by doogstar is perfect for this case.
& checkbox1.text will not at all help me....

Comment: Then you'll have to add the additional checkboxes (by name) to the HANDLES list on the end of the SUB definition.